# How to find value of Datagrid row that I have pressed 'DELETE' key on using WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

When pressing "DELETE" key on my keyboard I can remove items from a Datagrid. However, it is not removed from the SQLite database. I need to get the value or row number of the item that the user has pressed DELETE on in order to delete it from SQLite database.

XAML

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGridKeywords" PreviewKeyDown="dataGridKeywords_PreviewKeyDown" DockPanel.Dock="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="Auto" Margin="5,0,5,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="15" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" />
```

C#

```
private void dataGridKeywords_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Delete)
    {
        var grid = (DataGrid)sender;

        if (grid.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
        {
            String value = "???";
            String query = "DELETE FROM table WHERE value='" + value + "'";
        }
    }
} // dataGridKeywords_PreviewKeyDown
```

**Update, this is how I add items to my DataGrid:**

```
private void loadKeywordListKeywords(){
    // Create data table
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    DataColumn dataColumn1 = new DataColumn("Keyword", typeof(string));
    DataColumn dataColumn2 = new DataColumn("Regex", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add(dataColumn1);
    dt.Columns.Add(dataColumn2);

    // Connect to general db
    DBAdapterSQLite dbSoftware = new DBAdapterSQLite(config.databasePath, config.databaseFile, true);
    dbSoftware.open();

    // Fetch all keywords
    query = "SELECT keyword_id, keyword_value, keyword_is_regex FROM keyword_lists_keywords WHERE keyword_list_id=" + this.currentKeywordListId;
    using SQLiteDataReader reader = dbSoftware.queryRows(query);
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        int keywordId = reader.GetInt32(0);
        String keywordValue = reader.GetString(1);
        int keywordIsRegex = reader.GetInt32(2);


        // Add to Grid
        DataRow dataRow = dt.NewRow();
        dataRow[0] = keywordValue; 
        dataRow[1] = keywordIsRegex;

        // Add to list
        dt.Rows.Add(dataRow);
    }
    reader.Close();

    // Close db
    dbSoftware.close();

    // Add data to data grid
    dataGridKeywords.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
    dataGridKeywords.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
 } // loadKeywordListKeywords
```

Comment: grid.SelectedItem will be the instance of whatever type you've bound or set itemssource to.  Only you know what that is.  BTW  -  your sql string is just illustrative, right?

Comment: Yes, the string SQL is just illustrative offcourse. But how can I get the item value?

Comment: Like I said. grid.SelectedItem will be the instance of whatever type you've bound or set itemssource to. The item. Only you know what that is. Cast grid.SelectedItem to ( insert the your type here ).  Use whatever property from that is your unique key and you seem to want to call value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DataGrid` supports deletion of rows by default. It also exposes a routed `DataGrid.DeleteCommand`.

Pressing the *Del* key will execute the `DataGrid.DeleteCommand` too and automatically removes the currently selected row(s) from the `DataGrid`.

All you have to do is to subscribe to the `CommandManager.PreviewExecuted` attached event:

```
<DataGrid CommandManager.PreviewExecuted="DeleteSqlRow_OnPreviewExecuted">
  <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn>

      <!-- Add a delete button column which uses the integrated delete command -->
      <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <Button Content="X" Command="{x:Static DataGrid.DeleteCommand}" />
        </DataTemplate>
      </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
  </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Handle the removed items:

```
private void DeleteSqlRow_OnPreviewExecuted(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Command == DataGrid.DeleteCommand)
  {
    var multiSelector = e.Source as MultiSelector;

    // In case the data source of the DataGrid is a DataTable, 
    // the selected items are DataRowView instances.
    // Otherwise the selected items are the the items contained in the DataGrid.ItemsSource
    IEnumerable<DataRowView> deletedItems = multiSelector.SelectedItems.Cast<DataRowView>();

    foreach (DataRowView deletedItem in deletedItems)
    {
      var value = deletedItem["Keyword"];
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This works, but what is "deletedItems"? I tried to print it and got "System.Windows.Controls.SelectedItemCollection". I need the value of the column to be deleted or row id.

Comment: The variable is a collection containing the items removed from the `DataGrid`. You have to cast the collection using `Enumerable.Cast<T>()`. See the updated example.

Comment: What is MyDataItemType? I only use Strings. When chaning MyDataItemType to String i get this: System.Linq.Enumerable+<CastIterator>d__97`1[System.String]

Comment: You have to replace MyDataItemType with theactual type of the items contained in `DataGrid.ItemsSource`.

Comment: Its one string and one int. I've updated my code on how I add them to the DataGrid.

Comment: I have adjusted the answer.